# Java Threads calling methods on common Data Collector Object possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, servlets, jax-rs

**The idea:** I have a JAX-RS webservice servlet (Object called `webServlet`) which instantiates a data collecting Object `dataCollector` and passes this object on to multiple threads in their constructor. These threads query websites for results and then call the `dataCollector.add(result)` method to add the results to a Queue within the shared `dataCollector`.

**I have two questions regarding this idea:**

1) Can multiple threads call methods of a single shared object at the same time?

2) How does my `webServlet` object check when all threads are terminated to render a result page? Do I have to let my `webServlet` wait while all threads are running so I have a complete result list and how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, but perhaps not safely. In particular, if the queue in your dataCollector isn't a thread-safe queue like a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), you run the risk of a [ConcurrentModificationException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) when a thread calls add() on it.

2) a) Use an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (perhaps obtained from [Executors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)) to [submit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) [Callables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) or [Runnables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). Keep the [Futures](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) that are returned and use [get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) to wait until he work is done.

b) You don't *have* to. The choice is up to you. If you send the response before the work is done, you obviously won't have a complete result yet.

c) See a).

If this is all new to you, you may want to check out [Concurrency in the Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: My dataCollector would not be a ConcurrentLinkedQueue but a normal object that provides some more functionality like validating the data that is to be added to the queue, would that be problematic or is my object thread safe because it uses a thread safe queue?

Comment: @Jack: What I was trying to say is that the queue in the dataCollector must be thread-safe, or you're doomed to failure. Even if it is, you might get some surprising results if you're not fully familiar with the implications of sharing a resource across threads.

Comment: Yes, thank you for that, actually I am encountering surprising results because I am not at all familiar with sharing resources across threads. I asked a more specific question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723307/java-notify-main-class-when-all-threads-in-threadpool-are-finished-same-instan

Comment: [Answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723307/java-notify-main-class-when-all-threads-in-threadpool-are-finished-same-instan/6724781#6724781) over there. Let me know if it does/doesn't make sense :)